# Nested Function from another file does not access variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to access local variables from a function inside a file using a nested function imported from another file, but when I try to access it, it displays `undefined` instead.

File 1:

```js
import { getFirstName } from './getfirstname'

let name = { "fullname" : "John Doe" }

export class Class1 extends React.Component {
  getName = (x) => {
    var y = x.fullname
    getFirstName(y)
  }
}
getName(name);
```

File 2 (getfirstname.js) :

```
export const getFirstName = (z) => {
  var fname = z.split(/\|/).map(s => s .split (/\s+/) [0])
  console.log(fname)
}
```

How can I make sure using `getName(name)` returns `John` instead of `undefined`?

Edit: this working example should be more relevant to the question: https://codepen.io/marwann/pen/VwvRWrr

Comment: Where's the render method of render method of React component or have you removed it for brevity?

Comment: well you return nothing. getFirstName returns nothing. getName returns nothing. So you get undefined.

Comment: Your method for getFirstName is overly complicated, if you just have to get first name on the basis of space and there isn't an extra requirement simple way would be `const [fname] = z.split(" ");`

Comment: @ZainZafar rewrote a dummy example and removed parts that did not seem relevant to the question to me.

Comment: These callouts above are all correct, but the most salient issues is that `getName` is not defined in scope when you call it-- it is a method on the class but you attempt to call it directly in scope.  This is almost certainly throwing an error.  See my answer below.

Comment: Why are you using a `class` at all? There's no instance access, so you shouldn't be using a method. The `getName(name);` call would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code as posted:

1. Your `Class1` extends `React.Component` for no apparent reason
2. You define `getName` as a instance method of `Class1` but then try to call it directly, instead of as a property on an instance of `Class1`
3. You speak of "returning" but none of your code here returns anything-- it only logs to the console.

Ultimately, I don't think your issue is at all related to importing, and I suspect it is throwing an error when you try to call `getName` which does not exist in scope.

If we rewrite it with those things fixed, we should be able log a result:

```js
const getFirstName = (z) => {
  var fname = z.split(/\|/).map(s => s .split (/\s+/) [0])
  return fname
}

let name = { "fullname" : "John Doe" }

class Class1 {
  getName = (x) => {
    var y = x.fullname;
    return getFirstName(y);
  }
}

const instance = new Class1();

const fname = instance.getName(name);
console.log(fname);
```

Note that I've created an instance of your class and called `getName` from that instance.  I've additionally updated both `getName` and `getFirstName` to actually return a value.

A few other items to consider:

1. Nothing about your `class` as currently exists leverages the benefits you get from organizing your code into a `class`.  It might be worth considering whether or not it is actually necessary.
2. I would recommend against mixing `var` with `let` and `const`.  If you are working in an environment that allows you to leverage `let`/`const`, you can just replace any `var` with a `let` if it must be reassigned and a `const` if it will never be reassigned.

Comment: I think he kept it simple and removed non concerning parts.

Comment: Thank you. I had written a dummy example to ensure things were not overly complicated. The React part is indeed irrelevant inside the example. My main issue is to keep the two functions in separate files and ensure that the nested function actually accesses the variable from the parent function.

Comment: @Marwann - 
Yes, but note the two lines in my snippet `const instance = new Class1()` and `const fname = instance.getName(name)`; that is what solves your problem.  `getName` does not exist in the scope in which you are calling it-- it can only be accessed as a method on a `Class1` instance.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Brings me closer but I think my dummy code isn't good enough. How would I do if my `name` variable was defined inside `Class1()`? This is the actual case in my real issue.

Comment: _How would I do if my `name` variable was defined inside `Class1()?`_ Unfortunately, @Marwann, that statement doesn't really make sense to me.  You can't define a naked variable inside of a `class`.  You may define static and instance properties _of_ a `class`, and you can define variables inside methods of a `class`, but not a lone variables floating outside of any real scope.  I think if you want to get help for the specific issue you are facing you will have to update your question to include a [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: @AlexanderNied, after second thought, my question is a bit irrelevant. Here is the working example, except I want to have `getFirstName()` in another file: https://codepen.io/marwann/pen/VwvRWrr

Comment: @Marwann so is there something about the example that is not working as expected, or is the question simply "how do I move `getFirstName` to a different file?"

Comment: @AlexanderNied this is about moving getFirstName to another file!